# How to create validation from name range on another worksheet in excel using C#?

Tags: c#, excel, export-to-excel

I have create name range on sheet "A" so I need to use this range as validation ComboBox on sheet B. I want to know how can I setting validation as range using C#?

Comment: You want to know how to this programmatically? if so, what parts of this do you need help with (creating the range; setting the validation as the range, or...). Or you just want to know how to do it manually?

Comment: I want to know how to setting validation as range using C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sheets won't matter because you'll just reference the named range of the list value range. Here you go below (assumes Interop) - `listValidatingRange` is where you have your values that need to be displayed in the dropdown - add that as a named range. `cellThatNeedsValidating` is the cell that you want the drop-down to appear in - add that as a named range. Then, on `cellThatNeedsValidating`, add the validation to be that of `"=ListValidatingRange"`.

```
private void SetValidation()
{

    Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.NamedRange listValidatingRange =
        this.Controls.AddNamedRange(this.Range[""C1:C13"", missing],
        "ListValidatingRange");

    Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.NamedRange cellThatNeedsValidating =
        this.Controls.AddNamedRange(this.Range[""A1"", missing],
        "cellThatNeedsValidating");

    cellThatNeedsValidating.Validation.Add(
        Excel.XlDVType.xlValidateList ,
        Excel.XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertStop,
        missing, "=ListValidatingRange", missing);
}
```

Comment: It's work, however I need 4 hours before accept this as correct answer. Furthermore I have another relate question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497531/how-to-create-validation-range-from-value-that-input-by-user